# Segmentation fault after 2-d array allocation

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n,m,k,hours;
    std::cin >> n >> m >> k;
    hours = std::ceil(n * k / (float)m);
    int* checkers = new int[m];
    int** check = new int*[hours];
    for(int i(0); i < hours; i++)
        check[i] = new int[n];
    for(int i(0); i < n; i++)
        checkers[i] = (i + 1) % m;
    std::cout << check[0][0];

    return 0;
}
```

With specific input data like `20 4 1`, it returns Segmentation Fault when I'm trying to print check[0][0].
But if I replace `int* checkers = new int[m];` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n,m,k,hours;
    std::cin >> n >> m >> k;
    hours = std::ceil(n * k / (float)m);
    int** check = new int*[hours];
    for(int i(0); i < hours; i++)
        check[i] = new int[n];
    int* checkers = new int[m];
    for(int i(0); i < n; i++)
        checkers[i] = (i + 1) % m;
    std::cout << check[0][0];

    return 0;
}
```

It will return `` malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed. ``

How can I fix it?

P.S. With input, for example `3 1 1`, everything is alright.

Comment: change `checkers` `for loop` to `for(int i(0); i < m; i++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocated `m` elements for `checkers` while using `n` elements.

The number of elements to allocate and use should be matched (allocate `n` elements or use `m` elements, according to what you want to do).

Also note that the contents of `new int[n]` are not automatically initialized, so you cannot rely on the value of `check[0][0]`.